# WebMvcTest not working after removing deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Upgrading the SecurityConfig of my application, I got working version but destroyed so many tests.

Current, deprecated version is [here](https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/bitbank/config/SecurityConfiguration.java) and differecence between files is [here](https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/commit/f5c56bf296366b3b869f9135e343f32199227e6a#diff-c5af42375b7bf9cc397445c2e2606ad35b59de456e666b0fdd820e3b63bf281e)

The new version works very well (I tried it with Postman).

With difference version I got every test passed at 100%, now I have several errors that I
cannot solve myself.

E.g. this test:

```java
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
class AuthTokenFilterTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter;

    @MockBean
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @MockBean
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @MockBean
    UserDetails userDetails;

    @MockBean
    private PingService pingService;

    @MockBean
    AuthEntryPointJwt authEntryPointJwt;

    @MockBean
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Test
    void testCanReturnNullIfJwtIsMissing() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    /**
     * Test can validate the token.
     * 
     * Use /ping route because it is the route out of security, so we can
     * concentrate to the AuthTokenFilter class.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    void testCanValidateToken() throws Exception {
        String token = "a1.b2.c3";

        when(jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(token)).thenReturn(true);
        when(jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(token)).thenReturn("username");
        when(userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername("username")).thenReturn(userDetails);
        when(userDetails.getAuthorities()).thenReturn(null);

        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    /**
     * Test cannot validate the token.
     * 
     * Use /ping route because it is the route out of security, so we can
     * concentrate to the AuthTokenFilter class.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    void testCannotValidateToken() throws Exception {
        String token = "a1.b2.c3";
        when(jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(token)).thenReturn(false);
        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    /**
     * Test cannot validate the token if the header is missing.
     * 
     * Use /ping route because it is the route out of security, so we can
     * concentrate to the AuthTokenFilter class.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    void testCanReturnNullIfJwtIsMissingButOtherHeaderIsInPlace() throws Exception {
        String token = "a1.b2.c3";
        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ping").header("Authorization", "NotStartWithBearer " + token))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

I get

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bitbank.config.AuthTokenFilterTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authTokenFilter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bitbank.config.AuthTokenFilter' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

(The test is [here](https://github.com/sineverba/online-banking-backend/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/bitbank/config/AuthTokenFilterTest.java))

Or, in the RegisterControllerTest

```java
@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties", properties = "app.enableSubscription=false")
class RegisterControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter;

    @MockBean
    AuthEntryPointJwt authEntryPointJwt;

    @MockBean
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @MockBean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @MockBean
    Authentication authentication;

    @MockBean
    SecurityContext securityContext;

    @MockBean
    private RolesService rolesService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "username", authorities = { "ROLE_ADMIN" })
    void cannotRegisterUserWhenSubscriptionsAreDisabled() throws Exception {

        var userToSave = validUserEntity("username", "password");
        var savedUser = validUserEntity("username", "a1.b2.c3");

        when(userDetailsServiceImpl.post(userToSave)).thenReturn(savedUser);

        mvc.perform(post("/api/v1/auth/register/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(userToSave))).andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is("error")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("subscriptions disabled")));
    }

    private static UsersEntity validUserEntity(String username, String password) {
        return UsersEntity.builder().username(username).password(password).build();
    }
}
```

I get `Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'`

### SecurityConfig

Old:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt authEntryPointJwt;

    @Bean
    AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Value("${app.allowedOrigins}")
    private String allowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties;

    /**
     * Return allowedOrigins from application properties
     */
    private String getAllowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties() {
        return this.allowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Return the allowed origins.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private List<String> getAllowedOrigins() {
        String[] allowedOrigins = this.getAllowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties().split(",");
        return Arrays.asList(allowedOrigins);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPointJwt).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/ping").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/api/v1/auth/register").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/documentation").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(getAllowedOrigins());
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

and new

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    AuthEntryPointJwt authEntryPointJwt;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Value("${app.allowedOrigins}")
    private String allowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties;

    /**
     * Return allowedOrigins from application properties
     */
    private String getAllowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties() {
        return this.allowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Return the allowed origins.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private List<String> getAllowedOrigins() {
        String[] allowedOrigins = this.getAllowedOriginsFromApplicationProperties().split(",");
        return Arrays.asList(allowedOrigins);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPointJwt).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/ping").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/api/v1/auth/register").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/documentation").permitAll().mvcMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(getAllowedOrigins());
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your security config

Comment: Added (but they are visible also in repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cite the [documentation for `@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html):

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring MVC test that focuses only on Spring MVC components.
>
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

This means that your `SecurityConfiguration` is never created because Spring only focuses on the web layer and not your custom components.

You have two options for fixing this:

##### 1. Importing necessary beans

```java
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
class AuthTokenFilterTest {
```

Note, that you also need to import the configurations / components that your `SecurityConfiguration` relies on and all the classes these beans rely on, and so forth. So it would more likely have to look like this:

```java
@WebMvcTest(PingController.class)
@Import({SecurityConfiguration.class, UserDetailsServiceImpl.class, AuthEntryPointJwt.class})
class AuthTokenFilterTest {
```

This will however decrease the maintainability of your test. If you added a new dependency to say `UserDetailsServiceImpl`, your test would break again because the bean can't be found.

##### 2. Using [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html)

`@SpringBootTest` will create your whole application context with slight modifications for tests. The replacements would look like this:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc // <- included in WebMvcTest but not in SpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
class AuthTokenFilterTest {
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that the tests are slower because the *whole* application context is created and not only the web layer. I prefer this approach as I think that maintainability is more important than the speed of the execution of the tests.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. So, tests worked before my change because now SecurityConfig is a custom component and it is not automatically injected, right?

Comment: Yes, before it extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which Spring views as part of the web layer, therefore considering it for the `@WebMvcTest` application context creation